# Issue Passing Props After Fetch Request To Child Component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m having trouble passing the state data from a parent component to a child component. I’m not sure why this is happening, so any feedback is greatly appreciated.

My fetch request is returning the correct data when I console.log ‘this.state.episodeData’ in the componentDidMount() method in the parent component, but it is not showing in the console.log in the componentDidMount() method in the child component. What am I doing wrong?

I’ve simplified the example to show only the relevant fetch request and data handling:

Parent component

```
import React, { Component, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import TempComp from './tempComp';

export default class PostContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: '',
      episodeData: [],
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/episode/${id}/playlist`);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      episodeData: jsonData, //this is working!
      id: id
    });
    console.log('parent fetched data', this.state.episodeData)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <TempComp playlist={this.state.episodeData} />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TempComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(‘props in child component’, this.props.playlist)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default TempComp
```

Comment: Does this help you?? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-example-1xd67 You can check for the data received then call the child component.. Look at the console of the sandbox provided..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is called just the first time after the initial rendering of your component. This means that your child component is rendered before you finish your fetch request. In the parent component you are not seeing it, because `setState` works asynchronously and it is not done saving your state, when you try to print it out. If you want to see it, pass callback to setState:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/episode/${id}/playlist`);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      episodeData: jsonData, //this is working!
      id: id
    }, () => { 
        console.log('parent fetched data', this.state.episodeData)
    );
  }
```

In order to see the updated data in your child component, consider using `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  console.log('props in child component', this.props.playlist) ;
}
```